# Is this correct way to use "switch()" method in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, methods

Aim: To count links in footer section of a webpage.

Instead of this:

```
WebElement footerdriver=driver.findElement(By.id("gf-BIG"));
system.out.println(footerdriver.findElement(By.tagName("a")).size());
```

I want to write like this:

```
WebElement footerdriver=driver.findElement(By.id("gf-BIG"));
driver.switch(footerdriver);
system.out.println(driver.findElement(By.tagName("a")).size());
```

Is this correct way to use "switch()" method in selenium ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, switch() is not a method belonging to the Selenium Webdriver. The method switchTo() is used to change your focus to a different window, tab or iframe.

If I am understanding your question you want to find an element that is descending from a different element. The way to do this is just find the element using the WebElement method findElement(By locator). E.g:

```
driver.get("https://www.wikipedia.org/");
WebElement eng = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='js-link-box-en']"));
System.out.println(eng.findElement(By.tagName("span")).getText());
```

This will find a span element that descends from the element "eng".

[Here is a runnable example of a test using the method.](https://mx1.maxtaf.com/cases/bce3a4ad-a979-484d-86ef-d84544743bee?projectId=bugtestproject2)

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.switchTo();
```

should only be used to either switch to

1. iframes/frame/frameset
2. newly windows/tabs
3. Alerts
4. defaultContents

therefore,

```
WebElement footerdriver=driver.findElement(By.id("gf-BIG"));
driver.switch(footerdriver);
```

this is wrong since you are saying that you want to switch to a web element.

Also in selenium it is `switchTo()` not `switch`.